# nodejs API decide if create or update

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I created a nodejs API, where you can push new entries via POST, if the entry already exists, it should update it.

Now I have the issue that I check if the entry already exists via `findOne()` from mongoose, but it wont trigger the update function.

here is the code:

entry point via POST:

```
    exports.create_a_status = function(req, res) {
  if(read_status(req.body.hostname)){
    console.log("update")
    update(req,res)
  }    
  else{
    var new_status = new Status(req.body);
    new_status.save(function(err, status) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      history.create_a_history(req.body);
      res.json(status);
    });
  }
}
```

check if entry exists:

```
const read_status = function(hostname){
  Status.findOne({hostname: hostname},function(err,status){
    console.log(hostname)
    if (status){
      console.log(status)
      return status;
    }   
    return;
  })
}
```

and the update function, BUT this doesnt get triggered from `create_a_status()` :

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    // Update a status identified by the hostname in the request
   Status.findOneAndUpdate({hostname: req.params.hostname}, req.body,{new:true})
    .then((updatedStatus) => {
      res.json(updatedStatus);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      res.send(err);
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: all functions are in same file?

Comment: @Saeed.At yes, they're all in the same file.

Comment: `read_status`return immediately `undefined` cause `Status.findOne` is asynchronous and its result will be available only in its callback. This is why always only the `else` branch is executed.

Comment: NodeJS is asynchronous. Either use callbacks or promises (see general NodeJS documentation for the idea, Mongoose documentatiobn for the API)

Comment: @Dario Thanks! exactly what i missed.

Comment: For the record, how I understood the rest spec, POST to `server/endpoint` should create a new entry. And PUT to `server/endpoint/id` should update it. Although i don't know your requirements, I wonder how you tell the difference between a new entry and an existing entry with exactly the same content.

Comment: @Shilly No, as soon as the POST comes in, the API checks if the entry already exists, IF thats true, it should fire the `update(req,res)`, else it should fire the else block and create a new entry.

Comment: I understand that. I just wonder how you tell the difference between a new entry and an existing one.Anyways, darios comment describes the issue you have. Either use promises so you can return from inside read_status, or add a callabck function to read_status that can be used to handle the findOne results.

Comment: @Shilly I try that, but something isn't working atm, would be nice, if you can give me a snippet for that!

Comment: If anyone looking for Nodejs API boilerplate with Expressjs and MongoDB. Try this: https://github.com/maitraysuthar/rest-api-nodejs-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it with:

```
  exports.update_a_status = function(req, res) {
    // Update a status identified by the hostname in the request
   Status.findOneAndUpdate({hostname: req.body.hostname}, req.body,{upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true})
    .then((updatedStatus) => {
      res.json(updatedStatus);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      res.send(err);
    });
};
```

The point was the options in the `findOneAndUpdate()` function where I didnt set `upsert: true` what means if it doenst find an entry by hostname it will simply create it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following.
The same structure can be written with callbacks instead of promises. Or without using promisify() and wrapping the callbacks in your own new Promise() calls. It'll just be more code then.

```
// PROMISES VERSION
// We can import the promisify function from node util to turn our callbacks into promises.
const { promisify } = require( 'util' );
// Check if status exists.
// If exists, update it. Else create new status and new history.
// If anything throws an error, send it as the response.
const create_a_status = function( request, response ) {
Promise
    .resolve( request.body.hostname )
    .then( host => read_status( { host } ) )
    .then( status => status ? update_status( { 'hostname' : request.params.hostname, 'body' : request.body, 'new' : true } ) : new_status( request.body ) )
    .then( status => response.json( status ) );
    .catch( error => response.send( error ) );
    /* Depending on the function scopes, we might be able to omit all the x => y(x) calls.
    Promise
        .resolve( { 'host' : request.body.hostname } )
        .then( read_status )
        .then( status => status ? update_status( { 'hostname' : request.params.hostname, 'body' : request.body, 'new' : true } ) : new_status( request.body ) )
        .then( response.json );
        .catch( response.send );
    */
};
// Since we just need to return the status or error, we can just promisify the findOne method.
const read_status = promisify( Status.findOne.bind( Status ) );
// Since we just need to run the function and return, the .then().catch() in the create_a_status function will also fix this.
const update_status = promisify( Status.findOneAndUpdate.bind( Status ) );

const new_status = function( body ) {
    const status = new Status( body );
    const save = promisify( status.save.bind( status ) );
    return save
        .then( status => {
            history.create_a_history( body );
            return status;
        } );
};
```

Comment: getting error on `return save
        .then( status => {
            history.create_a_history( body );
            return status;
        } );`

called: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: save.then is not a function`

Comment: Have you tried if the promisify function actually works? Have you tried an explicit promise? : `const new_status = body => {
 return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) {
  const status = new Status( body );
  status.save( function( error, status ) {
   if ( error ) reject( error );
   else {
    history.create_a_history( body );
    resolve( status );
   }
  } );
 } );
};`

Comment: i got it to work, but in every case it just returns an empty object.